# How to merge two dataframes based on using the substring of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes based on a column. Ideally I would like to use startswith() as they won't always be exact matches.

df1:

```
       id    symbol
0      123      CCH
1      456     IAC1
2      789    MTCH1
3      987     CVLG
```

df2

```
        id       symbol
0       23434     CCHCP
1       35564    IAC1XP
2       76764     MTCH1
3       87877    CVLGPX
4       98765    CVLGPX
5       13234     CCHCP
```

and my desired output

```
         id      symbol    matched_id
0       23434     CCHCP       123
1       35564    IAC1XP       456
2       76764     MTCH1       789
3       87877    CVLGPX       987
4       98765    CVLGPXR      987
5       13234     CCH         123
```

So far I have used

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='symbol')
```

which works but only when there is a full match and fails on partials.
Any help advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
merged_df = (
    df2.assign(
        temp=df2.symbol.str.extract(pat=f"({'|'.join(df1.symbol)})"))
    .merge(
        df1,
        how='left',
        left_on='temp',
        right_on='symbol',
        suffixes=['', '_y'])
).rename(columns={'id_y': 'matched_id'}).drop(['temp', 'symbol_y'], 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
      id  symbol  matched_id
0  23434   CCHCP         123
1  35564  IAC1XP         456
2  76764   MTCH1         789
3  87877  CVLGPX         987
4  98765  CVLGPX         987
5  13234   CCHCP         123
```